# How to transform different shapes to circles in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-morphology

I have this image:

[image]

that has different shapes, and I want to transform each shape in a circle. And each circle must have different radius, depending on the size of the shape. How can I do that? With Morphology Operations or there are any function on Matlab that does that? 
I  used the function Regionprops to detect every individual shape, then I can do operations on each region separately.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `bwlabel` to first label all of the components. Then I would use `regionprops` to find the bounding box of each component. You can then use the `rectangle` with a `Curvature` value of `[1 1]` to plot an ellipse at each bounding box.

```
%// Load the image and convert to 0's and 1's
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wRYK.png');
img = double(img(:,:,1) > 0);

%// Label the image
L = bwlabel(img);

%// Compute region properties
P = regionprops(L);

imshow(img)

for k = 1:numel(P)
    %// Get the bounding box
    bb = P(k).BoundingBox;

    %// Plot an ellipse around each object
    hold on
    rectangle('Position', bb, ...
              'Curvature', [1 1], ...
              'EdgeColor', 'r', ...
              'LineWidth', 2);
end
```

[image]

If you actually want circles, you will need to decide how exactly you define a circle from a rectangle. For this, I just used the maximum of the width and height for the diameter.

```
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
cost = cos(t);
sint = sin(t);

for k = 1:numel(P)
    bb = P(k).BoundingBox;

    %// Compute the radius and center of the circle
    center = [bb(1)+0.5*bb(3), bb(2)+0.5*bb(4)];
    radius = max(bb(3:4)) / 2;

    %// Plot each circle
    plot(center(1) + radius * cost, ...
         center(2) + radius * sint, ...
         'Color', 'r');
end
```

[image]

Now if you actually want to modify the image *data* itself rather than simply displaying it, you can use a `meshgrid` of all of the pixel centers to test whether a given pixel is within a circle or not.

```
%// Create a new image the size of the old one
newImage = zeros(size(img));

%// Determine the x/y coordinates for each pixel
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(1:size(newImage, 2), 1:size(newImage, 1));
xy = [xx(:), yy(:)];

for k = 1:numel(P)
    bb = P(k).BoundingBox;

    %// Compute the circle that fits each bounding box
    center = [bb(1)+0.5*bb(3), bb(2)+0.5*bb(4)];
    radius = max(bb(3:4)) / 2;

    %// Now check if each pixel is within this circle
    incircle = sum(bsxfun(@minus, xy, center).^2, 2) <= radius^2;

    %// Change the values of newImage
    newImage(incircle) = k;
end

%// Create a binary mask of all points that were within any circle
mask = newImage > 0;
```

[image]

Comment: Such an complete answer, you're the best. Thank you for the help. That solved my problem